# Convertir numero entero a decimal

Tags: java, android-studio

Buen dia, estoy desarrollando una app para sacar promedios de asignaturas pero hay una opcion que sugiere al usuario cambiar los porcentajes de cada corte en cada materia, mi pregunta es como hago para que el porcentaje que el usuario introduzca, ejemplo 30, 30 y 40 cuando vaya a realizar la operacion en codigo eso lo convierta a 0.3, 0.3 y 0.4 para que el resultado salga en decimal, gracias

[image: HE aqui mi codigo por el momento pero cuando el usuario introduce los porcentajes el resultado lo bota 406.0 o 305.8 asi, deberia ser 4.06 o 3.05]

Answer (score 2):

Divide por 100, por ejemplo

```
porcentaje1=porcentaje1/100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Divides entre 100 el valor de  `promedio`, conviertes a `String` el valor de promedio y lo agregas a tu `TextView`:

```
promedio = promedio / 100;
String resultado = String.valueOf(promedio);
tv5.setText(resultado);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente multiplica el porcentaje por 0.01 y ya, por ejemplo:

```
porcentaje = porcentaje*0.01;
```

Comment: Tu respuesta no es muy diferente de las otras dos.

Comment: Ps solo es otra manera más de hacerlo, si la respuesta él cree que no le aporta ps simplemente no la califica, la idea acá es aportar, sea mucho o poco